# Can the Time Capsule back up multiple drives (internal and external) at the same time?

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule

I have a 500 GB internal HDD on my MacBook Pro and a second 500 GB external USB drive as well.

Is it possible to tell Time Machine to back both the internal and external drives up to one Time Capsule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - when you set the Time Machine to back up to the Time Capsule - you will include the internal drive by default.  I would let a couple of backups complete, and then go to the settings for time machine under options and make sure the external drive is not excluded. Kick off a a backup with the external drive connected to make sure it works.

If the drive isn't connected when a back up event arrives, the internal will get backed up - but the software will remember and resume backing up the external any time it is connected and a back up happens. You don't need to always have the external drive connected for this to work, you just lose some chances to back it up when it's not connected.